# Tiled Map Editor - Isometric View Problem

Tags: rendering, tiles, isometric

I'm using the latest version of Tiled Map Editor (0.9.1) to create isometric maps. I have objects that are larger than my tile size (64 x 32), so I am breaking them up into two tiles of the correct size. Below I show that the blue blocks are made of a top and a bottom (both of which are 64 x 32).

You can also see that when I am placing these blocks side by side, there is some strange rendering overlap. Shouldn't the foreground be showing if it is rendered in the correct order?

In that picture you can see 4 blocks stacked side by side with the problem, 2 blocks side by side with the problem, 1 block by itself without the problem, and 1 dissected block in its two components.

Anyone know what's up?

**Note: this is the view from within the Tiled Map Editor itself, not from within my game.**

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support question for a specific tool. You should post on the [Tiled bug tracker](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It's due to the tile graphic extending beyond the tile.

Update: I managed to work it out by playing with the tile layers. I placed foreground tiles in a layer below the background tiles.